# Simplest way to achieve client/server communications?

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, cross-domain

I am writing an application that fetches data from MS AX Dynamics once-in-a-very-long-while

The issue with AX (or with the company I am working for) is that AX does not allow cross domains connections.

Currently, we have 2 domains country1.company.com and country2.company.com on our Active Directory (AD) and the application is intended to run on both domains but AX is on country1.company.com. In fact, all country2 users RDP to country1 when they need to work on AX and it is terribly slow given our geographic distances.

To overcome this problem, I am thinking of writing a separate (console) program that runs at country1 such that users can send the data to it and let it query AX and return the results over the network.

The big question is:

Do I have to write the application like a client server thing or can i ride on existing windows features to acheive the same thing? Since I have zero network programming experience, I hope I dont have to go that way.... thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing a console app and sockets, you should make use of [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?ppud=4) classes. Yes, it is networking, but anything that talks to any other computer is. You probably want to set up a [WCF web service](http://blog.waleedmohamed.net/2008/06/getting-started-wcf-1.html) for this kind of feature. Here's a nice [starter app as an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebService.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use thrift [Link](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/).
It enables efficient and reliable communication across programming languages and also .
You just need to define the data structures and service interface in an IDL file. [Link](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/Tutorial)

Then use the thrift compiler to generate the RPC and data serialization code in one of the supported programming language of your choice.

With that you are equipped with the infrastructure needed for serializing your data and RPC. Now you can just focus on your business logic.

P.S: This is not a windows feature though.

Comment: +1 for good recommendation, but unfortunately I will not be able to fulfill the runtime requirements on the server. Thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: If you are creating a .NET application, thrift.dll is the only runtime requirement.  The thrift.dll can be built from the source available in the svn repository here : [thrift-trunk](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/) .    _lib/csharp/src/Thrift.csproj_ is the MS Build task to create Thrift.dll

Comment: thanks for the tip i missed.. i will review the this possibilty again. thanks.